# Swift Neo4j how to put a variable into quotation marks within Cypher Query?

Tags: swift, neo4j, cypher

Here is my code within my Swift Xcode Project:

```
@IBAction func runCypherTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        clientName = clientNameField.text

        guard let theo = self.theo else {
            log("Client not initialized yet")
            return
        }

        let result = theo.executeCypherSync("MATCH (c:Client) WHERE c.name = \(clientName) RETURN c.name as name, c.dob as dateOfBirth")
        switch result {
        case let .failure(error):
            log("Error while getting cypher results: \(error)")
        case let .success(queryResult):
            if let arrayClients = queryResult.rows[21]["name"] as? String {
                log("Asked via Cypher how many nodes there are with label 'name'. Answer: \(arrayClients)")

                query.append(arrayClients)
                print(query)
            } else {
                log("Got unexpected answer back")
```

I want to put my string variable `clientName` into the query but within quotation marks, Neo4j requires quotes around the property you wish to retrieve for example:

```
MATCH (c:Client) WHERE c.name = "Mr Smith"  RETURN c.name as name
```

With this in mind, I have tried interpolation and also escaping characters but nothing has been successful. I need the query above to print out but with "Mr Smith" instead defined by my clientName String variable.

FYI I get this when I print to the console:

```
WHERE c.name = \"Optional(\"Mr Smith\")\" RETURN c.name as name
```

You can see it puts the first quotation mark but not the second after Smith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to hardcode quotes in the Cypher query. You should just pass `clientName` as a string [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters), which could also make your query more efficient and secure:

```
let params: [String:PackProtocol] = ["clientName": clientName]
let result = theo.executeCypherSync(
  "MATCH (c:Client) WHERE c.name = $clientName RETURN c.name as name, c.dob as dateOfBirth",
  params: params)
```

Comment: This works way better than the way I did it, thank you for your help.